# Solr6 Querying multiple cores and normalizing scores

Tags: solr, information-retrieval

I have multiple cores(in different languages) that share the same structures/schemas.
I send the same query to each of the cores and return results that I then save into a new core called "results". I have a custom q parser plugin that saves scores so that that the results core can be ordered by the scores from the other cores.

Does it make sense to compare the scores from different collections? If I were to normalize the scores between 0 and 1 by dividing by the maximum score would this make the scores from the individual cores comparable for a particular query?

What would be the best way to make the scores normalized and comparable?

Apparently, the join command gives each of the results the same score.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you can compare scores depends on the type of ranking you have. If you basically only have Boolean field matching and some field weighting without any content similarity, then you could compare the scores across the cores.

But if you use some content similarity like the default similarity, then it becomes more work and you can no longer compare scores from a core. It depends on how much data you have and if the documents you indexed are well distributed over the cores. If it is well distributed, you could compare the scores as well. But then you need to make sure you have enough data indexed per core so it is representative and similar across the cores.

If this is not the case, you have to look up the Inverse Document Frequencies (IDF) per core given a query term. And use all the IDFs to calculate a new global IDF and use this to recalculate the document scores. Then you can compare.